# Add audtiting for endpoint

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, audit-logging

I was looking on the internet but unfortunately I couldn't find the answer. It seems to me that the topic is not clear and no solution seemed to be completely correct or complete. I need explanation step by step what and why.

For my REST API, I have a mongo database. For each request that comes to the endpoint, I would like to log such a request with the information what/who/when and what was in the body. I would like to log each such request with such information and then save it to the mongo db.
Example endpoint below.

```
@PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public WorkerDto createWorker(@RequestBody WorkerDto workerDto) {
        Worker worker = objectsMapper.dtoWorkerToWorker(workerDto);
        return objectsMapper.workerToDtoWorker(workerService.createWorker(worker));
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at HandlerInterceptor. You can also use aspect (aspectj)

Comment: Create a RequestScoped WorkerContext into a HandlerIntercepter and log it. Just all, also spring provides some builtin interceptors for that type of operations.